# Encrypting a p12 certificate

Tags: encryption, openssl, certificates

I'm trying to following this documentation ([see section Create a Code Signing Certificate](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/ios-code-signing/1231)) in oder to encrypt a p12 file but I always receive the same warning.

> unknown option 'Cert.p12'

Am I doing something wrong? This is the command I'm running

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -k -in "Cert.p12" -out "Cert.p12.encrypted"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a error in your command.  The `-k` option requires a password.

From the `man enc` page:

> -k password the password to derive the key from. This is for compatibility with previous versions of OpenSSL. Superseded by the
>   -pass argument.

As you can see, the option has been superseded by the `-pass` option.  Therefore a better interactive command for you would be (note the lack of the `-k` option):

```
openssl enc aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in "Cert.p12" -out "Cert.p12.encrypted"
```

at which point  it will prompt for a password.  If you must have the password in a script (which is dangerous) then use the `-k` option or the newer `-pass pass:<your password>`.  Read `man openssl`'s `PASS PHRASE ARGUMENTS` section for more secure ways of passing the password.

Note that you can drop the `enc`, which is implied when you specify a cipher and `-salt` which is enabled by default. You can therefore use:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -in "Cert.p12" -out "Cert.p12.encrypted"
```

The default option for `openssl` is to encrypt, so you don't need to instruct it to do so.  However, to decrypt you need to add the `-d` option:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -in "Cert.p12.encrypted" -out "Cert.p12.copy"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In order to decrypt do I need to follow a similar pattern?

Comment: Yes, with the `-d` option. I've edited the answer.